Plotly: Not able to update the legends when dropdown menu options are selected in plotly offine browser plot
I am trying to update the plotly plot with dropdown menu option using offline browser plot. The code is working well, however the legends for each trace does not get updated when the menu options are selected.
For all traces option I am able to see all 3 legends. However, for rest of the traces legends are not getting updated / not shown at all.
**
I tried  setting up visibility for legends separately. Used 'method': 'update' and   'method': 'restyle'. Nothing seems to work.**
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

# Sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)  # X axis
y1 = np.sin(x)  # red trace
y2 = np.cos(x)  # blue trace
y3 = np.sin(x) + np.cos(x)  # green trace

# Convert sample data to pandas DataFrame
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Red': y1, 'Blue': y2, 'Green': y3})

# Define the layout of the plot
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Plot with Dropdown Menu',
    xaxis=dict(title='X-axis Title'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Y-axis Title')
)

# Create an empty figure
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

# Define dropdown menu options
dropdown_options = [
    {'label': 'Option 1', 'value': 'all_visible'},   # all traces visible option
    {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': 'red_visible'},   # only red trace visible option
    {'label': 'Option 3', 'value': 'blue_visible'},  # only blue trace visible option
    {'label': 'Option 4', 'value': 'green_visible'}  # only green trace visible option
]

buttons = []

for option in dropdown_options:
    args = [{'visible': [False] * len(data_df.columns)}]
    legend_visibility = [True] * len(data_df.columns)  # Initialize legend visibility list
     
    if option['value'] == 'red_visible':
        args[0]['visible'][0] = True
        legend_visibility[1:] = [True] * (len(data_df.columns) - 1)  # Set legend visibility for visible traces
        
    elif option['value'] == 'blue_visible':
        args[0]['visible'][2] = True
        legend_visibility[2] = True
        
    elif option['value'] == 'green_visible':
        args[0]['visible'][0] = True
        legend_visibility[0] = True
        
    elif option['value'] == 'all_visible':
        args[0]['visible'] = [True] * len(data_df.columns)
        legend_visibility[1:] = [True] * (len(data_df.columns) - 1)  # Set legend visibility for visible traces

    # Set legend visibility for each trace
    for i, trace in enumerate(fig.data):
        if i < len(legend_visibility):
            trace.visible = legend_visibility[i]

    button = {'method': 'update', 'label': option['label'], 'args': args}
    buttons.append(button)

updatemenus = [{'buttons': buttons, 'direction': 'down', 'showactive': True}]
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)

# Add traces to the figure
for column_name in data_df.columns:
    if column_name != 'X':
        trace = go.Scatter(x=data_df['X'], y=data_df[column_name], mode='lines', name=column_name, visible=False)
        fig.add_trace(trace)

plot(fig)


My modification is to show the legend in the initial graph. This will allow the legend to be displayed for each selection. The line color defaults to blue in the first color, so when creating the graph, lowercase the column name and specify it as the line color. This will match the initial graph and the respective line color.

Show legend

# Create an empty figure
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

# Show legend 
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)


Line color update

# Add traces to the figure
for column_name in data_df.columns:
    if column_name != 'X':
        trace = go.Scatter(x=data_df['X'],
                           y=data_df[column_name],
                           mode='lines',
                           name=column_name,
                           line=dict(color=column_name.lower()), # line color setting
                           visible=False
                          )
        fig.add_trace(trace)


